# Replacing the "backslash" icon \ in a table within Excel Power Query-editor

Tags: excel, special-characters, powerquery

I've this problem in Power Query where I perform "replace value" on some columns, where I want `\` to be replaced by `_`
For some reason this doesn't work, I allready tried \, \\ and \\\ but none seem to work.

I'm still a novice in Power Query, but it's the first time I can't seem to figure out such a stupid thing 
If I use ctrl+F in Excel, this works, so I suspect that the \ charachter is ignored or so...

The code:
`= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Type gewijzigd1","\","_",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Repère complet", "Source", "Detail #(lf)source", "Destination", "Detail #(lf)Destination"})`

[link to a printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjWhh.png)

*edit: ctrl+F does work in an Excel, but only with the right `\` apparently the backslash has multiple character variants, although they all look the same. Unfortunately no effect in Power Query by using the right one

Answer (score 1):

Try using Replacer.ReplaceText instead of Replacer.ReplaceValue